# WPF Custom control in WinForms with floating precision size

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I was wondering is it possible to create a panel-like control in wpf, and another wpf custom control that will be the child of this panel, all in WinForms application. And then, would it be possible to set the custom control's size in float?
Also would I be able to rotate that custom control?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the [`System.Windows.Forms.Integration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms604571.aspx) NameSpace, more specifically the [ElementHost Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx), that will allow you to embed a WPF Control in Winforms.

---

This is a quick and simple demonstration of changing the WPF UserControls Child UserControls Size and Location. I will leave the animation to you.

**Main Winform Form**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.Integration;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        ElementHost host;
        WpfControlLibrary1.UserControl1 uc;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            host = new ElementHost();
            host.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
            uc = new WpfControlLibrary1.UserControl1();
            host.Child = uc;
            this.Controls.Add(host);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            uc.SetChildLocation =  new  System.Windows.Point(uc.SetChildLocation.X + 25.5, uc.SetChildLocation.Y + 10.2);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            uc.SetChildSize = new System.Windows.Size(uc.SetChildSize.Width + .25, uc.SetChildSize.Height + .25);
        }
    }
}
```

**UserControl1.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfControlLibrary1.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" Background="Red" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WpfControlLibrary1">
    <Canvas>
        <my:UserControl2 HorizontalAlignment="Center"   x:Name="userControl21" VerticalAlignment="Center" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" />

    </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

**UserControl1.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfControlLibrary1  
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for UserControl1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Point  SetChildLocation
        {
            get
            {
                return new Point(Canvas.GetLeft(userControl21), Canvas.GetTop(userControl21));
            }

            set
            {
                Canvas.SetLeft(userControl21, value.X);
                Canvas.SetTop(userControl21, value.Y);
            }
        }

        public Size SetChildSize
        {
            get
            {
                return new Size(userControl21.ActualWidth, userControl21.ActualHeight);
            }
            set
            {
                userControl21.Width = value.Width;
                userControl21.Height = value.Height;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UserControl2.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfControlLibrary1.UserControl2"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" SizeChanged="UserControl_SizeChanged">
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle x:Name="rect" Fill="Blue" Height="40" Width="120"></Rectangle>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**UserControl2.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfControlLibrary1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for UserControl2.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class UserControl2 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void UserControl_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            rect.Width = e.NewSize.Width;
            rect.Height = e.NewSize.Height;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I have a small favor to ask, would it be possible for you to give me an example on how to do it?
I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @user1806687 I will see what I can come up with

Comment: Wow, thank you very much!

I will get back at you when I try it out.

Thanks again! :D

Comment: @user1806687 I created a seperate WpfUserControl Library project and added a project reference to the Winform Project.